# adjust image in table with text, too

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to adjust the images with their respective texts below each image.

There are four images in one line. and other four in second line.

when I remove the any image from **first line** , then from the **second line** , first image should be placed to the last of the **first line**.

just like **Queue**

```html
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!--First Row-->
                    <!--Speaker 1 -->
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                    style=
                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding=
                                    "0" cellspacing="0" style=
                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"
                                    width="110">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" height="110"
                                                valign="top" width="110">
                                                    <p style=
                                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                                    <a class="modimg" href="#"
                                                    style=
                                                    "text-decoration: none!important;">
                                                    <img alt="" border="0" height=
                                                    "110" src=
                                                    "http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455301580.jpeg"
                                                    style=
                                                    "display: block !important; border: 3px solid #ffcbbc ; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                                    width="110"></a></p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="h2" style=
                                "font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 0px;color:#ffffff;">
                                <p style=
                                "padding: 0; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 110px; text-align: center;font-size: 10px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Mr. Mahesh
                                    Murthy</span></p>
                                    <p style=
                                    "padding:0; margin:0 auto;text-align: center !important; max-width:110px; font-size: 8px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Co-Founder at
                                    Seefund</span></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table><!--Speaker 2-->
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                    style=
                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0 auto; margin-left: 15px;">
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding=
                                    "0" cellspacing="0" style=
                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"
                                    width="110">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" height="100"
                                                valign="top" width="110">
                                                    <p style=
                                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                                    <a class="modimg" href="#"
                                                    style=
                                                    "text-decoration: none!important;">
                                                    <img alt="" border="0" height=
                                                    "110" src=
                                                    "http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg"
                                                    style=
                                                    "display: block !important; border: 3px solid #ffcbbc ; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                                    width="110"></a></p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="h2" style=
                                "font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 0px;color:#ffffff;">
                                <p style=
                                "padding: 0; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 110px; text-align: center;font-size: 10px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Mr. R.
                                    Chandrasekhar</span></p>
                                    <p style=
                                    "padding:0; margin:0 auto; max-width:110px;text-align: center !important; font-size: 8px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">President at
                                    NASSCOM</span></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table><!--Speaker 3 -->
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                    style=
                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0 auto; margin-left: 15px;">
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding=
                                    "0" cellspacing="0" style=
                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"
                                    width="120">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" height="100"
                                                valign="top" width="100">
                                                    <p style=
                                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                                    <a class="modimg" href="#"
                                                    style=
                                                    "text-decoration: none!important;">
                                                    <img alt="" border="0" height=
                                                    "110" src=
                                                    "http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455627060.jpeg"
                                                    style=
                                                    "display: block !important; border: 3px solid #ffcbbc ; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                                    width="110"></a></p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="h2" style=
                                " font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 0px;color:#ffffff;">
                                <p style=
                                " padding: 0; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 110px; text-align: center;font-size: 10px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Mr. Jay
                                    Panda</span></p>
                                    <p style=
                                    "padding:0; margin:0 auto;text-align: center !important; max-width:110px; font-size: 8px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Member of
                                    Parliament</span></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table><!--Speaker 4 -->
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                    style=
                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0 auto; margin-left: 15px;">
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding=
                                    "0" cellspacing="0" style=
                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"
                                    width="120">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" height="100"
                                                valign="top" width="100">
                                                    <p style=
                                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                                    <a class="modimg" href="#"
                                                    style=
                                                    "text-decoration: none!important;">
                                                    <img alt="" border="0" height=
                                                    "110" src=
                                                    "http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455300140.jpeg"
                                                    style=
                                                    " display: block !important; border: 3px solid #ffcbbc ; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                                    width="110"></a></p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="h2" style=
                                " font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 0px;color:#ffffff;">
                                <p style=
                                " padding: 0; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 110px; text-align: center;font-size: 10px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Ms. Shazia
                                    Ilmi</span></p>
                                    <p style=
                                    "padding:0; margin:0 auto;text-align: center !important; max-width:110px; font-size: 8px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Spokesperson at
                                    BJP</span></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr><!--More Speakers-->
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!--Second Row-->
                    <!--Speaker 5 -->
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                    style=
                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding=
                                    "0" cellspacing="0" style=
                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"
                                    width="120">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" height="100"
                                                valign="top" width="100">
                                                    <p style=
                                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                                    <a class="modimg" href="#"
                                                    style=
                                                    "text-decoration: none!important;">
                                                    <img alt="" border="0" height=
                                                    "110" src=
                                                    "http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455299755.jpeg"
                                                    style=
                                                    " display: block !important; border: 3px solid #ffcbbc ; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                                    width="110"></a></p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="h2" style=
                                " font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 0px;color:#ffffff;">
                                <p style=
                                " padding: 0; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 110px; text-align: center;font-size: 10px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Mr. Alok
                                    Bansal</span></p>
                                    <p style=
                                    "padding:0; margin:0 auto;text-align: center; max-width:110px; font-size: 8px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Co-Founder at
                                    Policybazaar</span></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table><!--Speaker 6-->
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                    style=
                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0 auto; margin-left: 15px;">
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding=
                                    "0" cellspacing="0" style=
                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"
                                    width="120">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" height="100"
                                                valign="top" width="100">
                                                    <p style=
                                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                                    <a class="modimg" href="#"
                                                    style=
                                                    "text-decoration: none!important;">
                                                    <img alt="" border="0" height=
                                                    "110" src=
                                                    "http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455298163.jpeg"
                                                    style=
                                                    " display: block !important; border: 3px solid #ffcbbc ; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                                    width="110"></a></p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="h2" style=
                                " font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 0px;color:#ffffff;">
                                <p style=
                                " padding: 0; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 110px; text-align: center;font-size: 10px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Mr. Arjun
                                    Handa</span></p>
                                    <p style=
                                    "padding:0; margin:0 auto;text-align: center !important; max-width:110px; font-size: 8px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Vice chairmain and
                                    MD at Claris Life Sciences</span></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table><!--Speaker 7 -->
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                    style=
                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0 auto; margin-left: 15px;">
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding=
                                    "0" cellspacing="0" style=
                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"
                                    width="120">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" height="100"
                                                valign="top" width="100">
                                                    <p style=
                                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                                    <a class="modimg" href="#"
                                                    style=
                                                    "text-decoration: none!important;">
                                                    <img alt="" border="0" height=
                                                    "110" src=
                                                    "http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455297276.jpeg"
                                                    style=
                                                    " display: block !important; border: 3px solid #ffcbbc ; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                                    width="110"></a></p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="h2" style=
                                " font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 0px;color:#ffffff;">
                                <p style=
                                " padding: 0px; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 110px; text-align: center;font-size: 10px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Ms. Padmaja
                                    Ruparel</span></p>
                                    <p style=
                                    "padding:0; margin:0 auto;text-align: center !important; max-width:110px; font-size: 8px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">President Indian
                                    Angel Network</span></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table><!--Speaker 8 -->
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                    style=
                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0 auto; margin-left: 15px;">
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding=
                                    "0" cellspacing="0" style=
                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"
                                    width="120">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" height="100"
                                                valign="top" width="100">
                                                    <p style=
                                                    "border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                                    <a class="modimg" href="#"
                                                    style=
                                                    "text-decoration: none!important;">
                                                    <img alt="" border="0" height=
                                                    "110" src=
                                                    "http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455797754.png"
                                                    style=
                                                    " display: block !important; border: 3px solid #ffcbbc ; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                                    width="110"></a></p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="h2" style=
                                " font-weight: bold ;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;padding-top: 2px;padding-bottom: 0px;color:#ffffff;">
                                <p style=
                                " padding: 0; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 110px; text-align: center;font-size: 10px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">Mr. Sanjay
                                    Randhar</span></p>
                                    <p style=
                                    "padding:0; margin:0 auto;text-align: center !important; max-width:110px; font-size: 8px;">
                                    <span class="wrap_textbox">MD at
                                    GVFL</span></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

What I have tried is ,

```html
<table style="width: 600px">
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455797754.png" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        
        
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455300140.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455299755.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455298163.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
       
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455797754.png" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But there is not text adjustment with respective image.

PS: I have to use `table` and **inline css** , only.

Thank You.

Comment: as i can see the first 4 are on one row, the next 4 imgs are on another row. so they will ALWAYS stay separately so with that html you can't remove one image from first row, and the first img from second row to go to first row. it's impossible with that html structure

Comment: exactly.. so what I want to do it.. if there is possible then only one row. and if there are 8 images then first four to one line and another four images to the new line. and if i remove any on the first line then from the second line the first image should be to the last of first line. so i want to do like that.

Comment: you can change the behaviour of the table and the td elements. see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well....one solution would be to put them all in the same row, and change the `display` of the `table` and of the `td` elements. so they will behave like `block` and `inline-block` elements. that way, you can set 4 `td` on each line , even if all 8 of them are in the same row ( in HTML ) , by using `width:25%;display:inline-block`

i wrote CSS because it was faster and easier for me and maybe better to understand, but you can copy the CSS and use it as inline CSS .

in my example i've hidden the first `td` with text `TITLE1`  so you can see that the 5th `td` ( first on the second row with text TITLE5 ) moves on the first row as the 4th td

let me know if it works for you

```css
table { width:100%;display:block;text-align:center;}
table td { width:25%;display:inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;vertical-align: top;}
table td img { max-width:100%;}
table td span { word-break:break-word;}
td:first-child { display:none}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  TITLE1
  </td>
  <td><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<span>TITLE2TITLE2TITLE2TITLE2TITLE2TITLE2TITLE2TITLE2</span>
  </td>
  <td><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  TITLE3
  </td>
  <td><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  TITLE4
  </td>
  <td><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    TITLE5
  </td>
  <td><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    TITLE6
  </td>
  <td><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      TITLE7
</td>
<td><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  TITLE8
     </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: not worked. Text is overflowing. text should be to the width of image and if text is long then it should be down to the new line. I have done in my 1st snippet code. just like that i want it. but the only thing i want is without using two `tr`

Comment: well if text is overflowing use `word-break:break-word;` on the text. the solution above it's working. it's using only using one tr. it's a simplified version of your html

Comment: it worked. but now what's the issue is that when i expand text then , that particular image goes to up , rather than all images height should be same and the rest of images below that line should go down.

Comment: add `vertical-align: top;` on the `td`

Comment: yeah... but when i remove first image then from the next line image gets up to the first line . but the other three images would be in the middle of the line. so is it possible? i have tired using `margin:0 auto`. if there is one image in the second line then also it would be on center of second line.

Comment: use `text-align:center;` on the `table` . edited my answer with all the adjustments

Comment: oh yeah... got it... thanks a lot... you are amazing... :)

Comment: just one thing.. as i m new to html email so , when i give background to the text below image, there is little `padding-left`.

Comment: `<td style="vertical-align:top;width:20%;display:inline-block;margin-left:20px;padding:0 auto;text-align:center;">
                                        <img style=" display: block !important; " alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455301580.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" >

                                        <p style="word-break: break-all; max-width: 110px; padding: 0 auto; margin: 0 auto; background: #FFFFFF;">XYZ</p>
                                 
                                    </td>`

Comment: check the width of the `p` ( text ) . if it's not `100%` the width of the `td` then there will be spaces left and right.  i suggest you use `width:100%` on `p` so it will have the width of the `td` and maybe use `padding :0 5px` ( also on `p` ) so it looks nicely

Answer (score 0):

well...again your question...nothing to do because you are using a table with fixed width and only one td..use javascript to delete whole span..if u delete a image on first row, the first image of second row will automatically will place to the last position of first row.
look my first snippet with 8 images..

```html
<table style="width: 600px">
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455797754.png" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        
        
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455300140.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455299755.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455298163.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
       
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455797754.png" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        
        
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455300140.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455299755.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455298163.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And check my second snippet after deleting the second image of first row.

```html
<table style="width: 600px">
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455797754.png" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455299755.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455298163.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
       
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455797754.png" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        
        
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455300140.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455299755.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 116px;margin-left: 15px">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455298163.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" ></a>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't use javascript. as I am making HTML emailer. That's why have to stick to table and inline css

Comment: ok then you can only html. you can delete an image in other way..but i think your problem is solved that you have asked...@user123

Comment: you are setting a fixed width on the `span` elements. that's not recommended if you want to have a modern, responsive layout